# Make the timeframe selection "sticky" on the new users page

Tags: feature-request, users-page

It would be nice if whatever timeframe I last selected on the users page was used as the timeframe when I next visit the users page.

Comment: one tricky snag here is that the "new users" will not have a timeframe it will have different orders (rep/creation date)

Comment: @waffles: Perhaps just sticky within each tab, then?

Comment: how sticky do you want it?

Comment: @waffles: Personally, I'd like "all" to be the default, but I figure that's not going to happen, so I'd like to be able to click "all" once and have it stay there (permanently) until I change it.

Comment: aha ... per user sticky I follow ... not against that